# How to update only one specific property of nested object in associative array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have associative array.
It's a key(number) and value(object).
I need to keep state of this array same as it is I just need to update one object property.
Example of array:

```
5678: {OrderId: 1, Title: "Example 1", Users: [{UserId: 1}, {UserId: 2}, {UserId: 3}]}
5679: {OrderId: 2, Title: "Example 2", Users: [{UserId: 1}, {UserId: 2}, {UserId: 3}]}
```

I need to update `Users` array property.
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
ordersAssociativeArray: {
        ...state.ordersAssociativeArray,
        [action.key]: {
          ...state.ordersAssociativeArray[action.key],
          Users: action.updatedUsers
        }
      }
```

This is data inside reducer.
What I did wrong how to fix this?
Something that might help.
When I inspect values in chrome I check previous value and value after execution of my code above:

Before:

```
ordersAssociativeArray:Array(22) > 5678: Order {OrderId: ...}
```

After:

```
ordersAssociativeArray: > 5678: {OrderId: ...}
```

Solution (code in my reducer)

```
let temp = Object.assign([], state.ordersAssociativeArray);
temp[action.key].Users = action.updatedUsers;
return {
      ...state,
      ordersAssociativeArray: temp
}
```

So this code is working fine.
But I still don't understand why? So I have solution but would like if someone can explain me why this way is working and first not?
If it could help here how I put objects in this associative array initialy:

```
ordersAssociativeArray[someID] = someObject // this object is created by 'new Order(par1, par2 etc.)'
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code to your reducer, the function you're executing?

Comment: What is the original ordersAssociativeArray type? It seems like it's an array? If it's an array, you need to use array to merge data.

Comment: you should check out `immutability-helper` (https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)

Comment: @Chen-TaiHou Can you show some example what do you mean by using array to merge data. As you can see it's 'Array' first but later it's object

Comment: Post entire reducer code, current snippet is not wrong, but it is too general. I suggest writing tests for your reducer. You'll be easily able to analyse your problem with test output.

Comment: Do you realize that Javascript doesn't have associative arrays in the way that some other languages do.  It has actual arrays and it has plain objects (which can sometimes be accessed in an array-like manner) and it has Maps.  It would be best if you used terminology that matches what you're actually using.

Comment: So what is this that I am using, sorry still learning

Comment: Have you played with the code in my fiddle? Your first example is correct, if I have reproduced it accurately, albeit a little hard on the eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct, as demonstrated by [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8cckpzt/1/). There may be problem somewhere else in your code.

Something that I would recommend for you is to separate your reducer into two functions, `ordersReducer` and `orderReducer`. This way you will avoid the excessive use of dots, which may be what caused you to doubt the correctness of your code.

For example, something like:

```
const ordersReducer = (state, action) => {
  const order = state[action.key]

  return {
    ...state,
    [action.key]: orderReducer(order, action)
  }
}

const orderReducer = (state, action) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    Users: action.updatedUsers
  }
}
```

I hope you find your bug!

**Update**

In your solution you use `let temp = Object.assign([], state.ordersAssociativeArray);`. This is fine, but I thought you should know that it is sometimes preferable to use a `{}` even when you are indexing by numbers.

Arrays in javascript aren't great for representing normalized data, because if an id is missing the js array will still have an `undefined` entry at that index. For example,

```
const orders = []
array[5000] = 1 // now my array has 4999 undefined entries
```

If you use an object with integer keys, on the other hand, you get nice tightly packed entries.

```
const orders = {}
orders[5000] = 1 // { 5000: 1 } no undefined entries
```

Here is an article about [normalizing state shape](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) in redux. Notice how they migrate from using an array in the original example, to an object with keys like `users1`.

Comment: I updated it but mess something. Basically I am trying to reproduce what I have. Named objects in state. https://jsfiddle.net/o8cckpzt/2/

Comment: And in that second case how do you loop through it or try to get specific object like: let obj = orders[5000];

Comment: I will add some examples to the fiddle.

Comment: Here, I've added to your fiddle with some examples at the bottom: https://jsfiddle.net/o8cckpzt/3/

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be that you're using array in the state but in the reducer you're putting as object. Try doing:

```
ordersAssociativeArray: [     //an array and not an object
    ...state.ordersAssociativeArray,
    [action.key]: {
        ...state.ordersAssociativeArray[action.key],
        Users: action.updatedUsers
    }
]
```

It will put ordersAssociative array in your state and not an object.

Comment: I tried this and I get syntax error on this '[action.OrderId]: {' => '[js] ',' expected.'

Comment: That is some syntactical error or error somewhere else in the code. Probably where you're accessing `userJobId`. Can you please give some more code.

Comment: Although I'm pretty much sure that the issue of getting an object and not an array is the same as above.

Comment: It's still '[action.OrderId]: {' => '[js] ',' expected.'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159613/discussion-between-ajay-gaur-and-1110).

Comment: Check my question I added solution at the end

Comment: Don't make such kind of arrays. Either just make simple arrays or objects. It'll be little less confusing and then you can use immutibility-helper from react. https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper

I am still not impressed with your solution.

Comment: I still don't understand what is wrong with this array. It's not valid? What would be good alternative so I can access it like: let object = myArray[OBJECT_ID]